# Clarification on Preprint Submission Policy during Manuscript Review in Springer journal

Tags: arxiv, preprint, springer

I am currently facing a situation regarding the submission of a preprint while my manuscript is under review. I submitted my paper to The International Journal of Advances in Engineering Sciences and Applied Mathematics (Springer) in September, and it has been in "with editor" status since then.

I have contacted the Chief Editor for clarification on whether I am allowed to submit a preprint of my paper to platforms like arXiv while it is under review, but I have not received a clear response yet.

Has anyone encountered a similar situation with this journal or other journals published by Springer? What is the general practice regarding submitting preprints while a manuscript is under review? I am seeking advice and insights from the community to better understand the best course of action.

I am aware that journal policies can vary, and I have checked the journal's website for information without success. I'm reaching out to the community for guidance while I await a response from the Chief Editor.

Comment: In general, one can submit a preprint in ArXiv unless the journal prohibits this action. I think you don't have to take any permission from the editor. But you can check the section typically named such as " information for authors", if nothing mentioned about such prohibition then you can freely submit it to ArXiv because ArXiv is not considered as publication. I personally submit every paper to ArXiv before sending it to journal.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to ask, the answer is "yes you are allowed to post preprints".

> Springer Nature journals encourage posting of preprints of primary research manuscripts on preprint servers of the authors’ choice, authors’ or institutional websites, and open communications between researchers whether on community preprint servers or preprint commenting platforms.

[Source](https://www.springer.com/gp/editorial-policies/preprint-sharing)